# What is the exact reason of taking my site more time to load after 3-4 hours while on ideal position?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net, cache

When I refresh a page over and over, even with clearing the cache, it around takes 200ms for the HTML to load.

If I load the page after not looking at it for a few hours, it always takes around 25 seconds to return the HTML.

Is this an IIS cache problem - does the IIS cache expire?

Is there any way to extend the IIS cache to be 12 or 24 hours? Any suggestion will be apreciated.

Comment: please comment downvoters........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like MichelZ mentioned, IIS, by default, shuts down the worker process after 20 minutes of inactivity. It also recycles the process once every 29 hours.

all this behavior is configurable and you can change these numbers. If you right click on the application pool that runs your site, you will be able to see the 2 settings `Idle Time-out (minutes)` under `Process Model` you can change that to 0 to say infinite

[image]

and if you scroll a bit down you will see `Regular Time Interval (minutes)` under `Recycling` you can set that to 0 to say infinite

[image]

more over, you can look into [Application Initialization Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) that will help you auto-warm up your site if you want to

Comment: App Init might be overkill given the description, but otherwise, this!

Answer (score 2):

The IIS Worker Process shuts down after some minutes, and will need to load again when a request hits.

So have a google on how you can keep the IIS WP alive

Also, precompiling the ASP.NET application helps (also, lot of infos in google)